# Laravel 5 Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$basicdetails

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

what is my mistake?

my controller :

```
public function index()
{
    $employees = Employee::all();
    return view('employee.view_all_employee_details', compact('employees'));
}
```

My Employee Model function :

```
public function basicdetails()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App/EmployeeAdditionalDetail' , 'emp_id' , 'emp_id');
}
```

My EmployeeAdditionalDetail model :

```
public function employeeDetails()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee' , 'emp_id' , 'emp_id');
}
```

My View

```
@if(count($employees) > 0)

    @foreach($employees as $employee)
        <tr>
            <td> {{ $employee->first_name }} </td>
            <td> {{ $employee->manager_id }} </td>
            <td>

              {{ $employee->basicdetails->personal_email }} </p> **Error showing here**
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach

@else
    {!! "<tr><td>No Recod Found</td></tr>" !!}

@endif
```

My Error:

> ErrorException in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\socialhub\app\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController.php
>   line 22: Undefined property:
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$basicdetails

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is with the third parameter of $this->hasOne(..), it should be 'local_key', normally this would be 'id'.

Try removing the third parameter, or put the correct local_key:

```
public function basicdetails()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App/EmployeeAdditionalDetail' , 'emp_id');
}
```

Comment: ya i have removed. Now got a error : "Trying to get property of non-object"